# Наедине с самой собой / наедине сама с собой, – непринципиально?

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость, выбор-варианта

> Радуют меня и пустынные улицы старинных городов, укутанные в грёзы. И
>   возможность бродить в чужих дворцах, оставаясь **наедине с самой собой**.
>   И одиночество в ресторане, и тишина отеля – всё это дарит покоем.

Гуглятся оба варианта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Считаю, что лучше использовать то выражение, которое есть в тексте.

*Наедине с самой собой

Над гладью сизо-голубой

В бессчетных блестках серебра,

Где над водою спит гора.*

*Почти что в облачной стране,

С самой собой наедине...*
З. Миркина

Возможно, я не права, но *наедине сама с собой* мне нравится меньше (уж очень по форме смахивает на "тихо сам с собою").

2. *И одиночество в ресторане, и тишина отеля **—** все это дарит покоем.*

Вместо запятой я бы поставила тире.
[[По правилу](http://www.fio.ru/pravila/punktuatsiya/obobschennye-slova-pri-odnorodnykh-chlenakh-predlo/): если обобщающее слово следует за однородными членами, то перед ним ставится тире, например: *Ни столба, ни стога, ни забора — ничего не видно* (Лермонтов).]

Comment: Риммулик, тире я в тексте поставила (сама), а здесь - забыла. Поправлю, чтоб не слишком позориться. А  "тихо сам с собою" очень даже удачный пример "за" (а не "против")! Будем думать! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку текст прозаический и спокойный по стилю, "самой" здесь воспринимается как излишество или проявление сентиментального отношения рассказчицы к себе (уподобляется ступе с Бабою-Ягой). Смысловой выбор возможен был между *наедине с собой* или *с кем-то другим*. В стихах же вольность многословия может быть оправдана потребностями ритма строки, эмоциями и пр. - на них не стоит ориентироваться. Выражение "сам с собой" обычно подчеркивает нестандартность или абсурдность ситуации (*сам с собою веду беседу* или *она сама себя высекла!*).

Answer (score 1):

И возможность бродить в чужих дворцах, оставаясь **наедине с  собой.** И одиночество в ресторане, и тишина отеля – всё это дарит покоем.

Пояснение

1) Из словаря: НАЕДИНЕ, нареч. 1. Один на один, вдвоём, без свидетелей. Остаться н. с больным. Адвокат разговаривал с подсудимым н. Провести вечер н. с мужем. 2. **(обычно со сл.: с собой, с самим собой). Один, в одиночестве. Н. с собой.**

2) ***Наедине с самим собой*** — в Накорусе 105 примеров. Природу не любят только те, кто боится остаться наедине с самим собой. [Николай Сладков. Зарубки на памяти (1970-1996) // «Звезда», 2000]

***Наедине с самой собой*** — 0 примеров, ***наедине с собой*** — 272 примера.

Я думаю,что сочетание ***наедине с самой собой*** неблагозвучно из-за повтора падежа.